# Return the YTD value if nothing for ABC

Tags: sql, sql-server

The records for `timeframe` for `orderyear` 2019 field will not bring ABC until we receive the first entry for that year starting Jan of next year (2020). As a workaround, I do not want to leave with no value. Is there anyways until we start to see the numbers flow through for the ABC for `orderyear` 2019, I want YTD numbers to show up instead replacing the YTD value with ABC. I am using SSMS 2016. Can someone please provide assistance.

My Query:

```
select 
  orderyear, TimeFrame, min(fiscaldate) minimumdate,
  max(fiscaldate) maximumdate, sum(fiscalrevenue) revenue 
from mytable
group by orderyear, TimeFrame
order by 1 


orderyear   timeframe      minimumdate    maximumdate   revenue
2017         ABC           2018-01-01      2018-04-30   1056.38
2017         YTD           2017-01-04      2017-09-28   159.54
2018         ABC           2019-01-01      2019-04-30   1026.10
2018         YTD           2018-04-24      2018-09-27   2461.11
2019         YTD           2019-04-25      2019-09-25   3494.06
```

Requested:

```
orderyear   timeframe      minimumdate    maximumdate   revenue
2017         ABC           2018-01-01      2018-04-30   1056.38
2017         YTD           2017-01-04      2017-09-28   159.54
2018         ABC           2019-01-01      2019-04-30   1026.10
2018         YTD           2018-04-24      2018-09-27   2461.11
2019         YTD           2019-04-25      2019-09-25   3494.06
**2019       ABC           2019-04-25      2019-09-25   3494.06**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a window function, you can identify which yearly records don't have an 'abc'.  Then in a cross apply you can double up on those records.  Then proceed as usual from there:

```
select      orderyear,
            ap.TimeFrame,
            minimumDate = min(minimumDate),
            maximumDate = max(maximumDate),
            sum(revenue) revenue
from        (
                select  *, 
                        hasABC = 
                            max(iif(timeFrame = 'abc', 1, 0)) 
                            over (partition by orderYear)
                from    mytable
            ) t 
cross apply (
                select timeframe union all
                select 'ABC' where t.hasABC = 0
            ) ap
group by    orderyear, 
            ap.TimeFrame
order by    orderYear, timeframe
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want union all:

```
with ot as (
      select orderyear, TimeFrame, min(fiscaldate) as minimumdate,
max(fiscaldate) as maximumdate, sum(fiscalrevenue) as revenue 
      from mytable
      group by orderyear, TimeFrame
     )
select ot.*
from ot
union all
select ot.orderyear, 'ABC', ot.minimumdate, ot.maximumdate, ot.revenue
from ot
where ot.orderyear = year(getdate()) and ot.TimeFrame = 'YTD' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from ot ot2
                  where ot2.ot.orderyear = year(getdate()) and ot.TimeFrame = 'ABC'
                 )
order by 1, 2;
```

EDIT:

If you want this with one reference to the underlying table, I would suggest:

```
select orderyear, timeframe, minimumdate, maximumdate, revenue
from (select orderyear, TimeFrame, min(fiscaldate) as minimumdate,
    max(fiscaldate) as maximumdate, sum(fiscalrevenue) as revenue,
             max(orderyear) over () as max_year, 
             max(case when TimeFrame = 'ABC' then orderyear end) over () as max_abc_year
      from mytable
      group by orderyear, TimeFrame
     ) t cross apply
     (values (1, orderyear, timeframe, minimumdate, maximumdate, revenue),
             (2, orderyear, 'ABC', minimumdate, maximumdate, revenue)
     ) v(which, orderyear, timeframe, minimumdate, maximumdate, revenue)
where which = 1 or
      (orderyear = max_year) and max_abc_year < max_abc_year);
```

This runs the query and uses `cross apply` to duplicate the rows.  It selects the duplicated row only for the maximum year when there is no "ABC" record for that year.

Comment: I can't find a reference for v2016, but in the past my experience has been that a CTE gets reprocessed every time you call it.  So here, it would be called 3 times.  If the real case for aggregating over 'mytable' is costly, this would magnify that effect.

Comment: @pwilcox . . . For the volume of data in your question, that seems like a non-consideration.